# How folder modification time affects unison file synchronization? (Windows)

Tags: windows, sync, rsync, unison

**I used unison to mirror a folder in Windows (using options -force and -times).**

It worked well, but the folders modification time has changed in the destination and now original and new folders differs while, as expected, files have the same modification times in boot roots (source and destination).

In my case, it is useful to have the real "modification time" also in folders, and I know how to synchronize this using rsync. I used other tools in the past, like robocopy and it maintains the folder modification time.

My questions are:

- **If I use rsync to sync folder modification time how it could affect future unison analysis and synchronization?**
- **In case I left the mirrored folders with the new date how it could affect other tools or windows processes?**

(1) rsync used: `rsync -Pr --times --size-only --existing`